# How do i get the codec's List of ffmpeg by names?

Tags: c++-cli

I have this function in C

```
int Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType()
{
    if (current_codec != NULL)
        return (int) current_codec->type;
    return AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

But the function return the code of each codec type. 
Like: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

If i'm doing for the test in the function i type: `AVMediaType::`
Then i see the List of all 7 codec's types there is for example:

```
AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
```

So i want to make a function like the one with the int but `string` or `const char*` that will return me the names of the types and not the codes.

How can i do it ?

**EDIT**

In the C file i did:

```
const char* Encoder_av_get_media_type_string(enum AVMediaType media_type)
{
    switch (media_type) {
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:      return "video";
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:      return "audio";
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA:       return "data";
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE:   return "subtitle";
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_ATTACHMENT: return "attachment";
        default:                      return NULL;
        }
}
```

Then in the header file that connecting between the C and C++ i did:

```
const char* Encoder_av_get_media_type_string(enum AVMediaType media_type);
```

Then in the C++ header file i did:

```
property List<String^> ^GetCodec
{

    List<String^>^ get()
    {
        List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;
        String ^s;


        s = gcnew String(Encoder_av_get_media_type_string(avm));
        l->Add(s);


        return l;
    }
}
```

Then in CSHARP i did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < f.GetCodec.Count; i++)
            {
                ss.Add(f.GetCodec[i]);
            }
```

So maybe in C++ it shouldn't be property i thought to do something that in CSHARP when i make f.GetCodec. then it will show me a List of all the codec's types names.

Like a property like when i'm doing f.GetCodec.Add and see list of properties so f.GetCodec.(and here i will the list of all types names)

If it's impossible then just to make in CSHARP a List with all types names.

But for now i'm getting only 1 name "video" that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__misc.html), there exists a function to do just that.

```
const char* av_get_media_type_string(enum AVMediaType media_type)
```

Comment: I used this function but i'm getting in my List only on name. I'm updating my question with the code.

Comment: Updated my question please look at it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `avm` changing anywhere, so I don't see how you're expecting the string to vary :o